# Dynamically load JSX file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a wrapper API file for a ReactJS component.

For example, /js/test.react.js

```
   /** @jsx React.DOM */
var TESTCLASS = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div> Test </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I have written a wrapper JavaScript file for that:

```
var testClass = {
    load: function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/jsx";
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        script.onload = function(){
            React.render(
                <TESTCLASS/>,
                document.body)
        };
        script.src ="./js/test.react.js";
    }
};
```

Then I can use the wrapper API JavaScript in a third-party HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content"></div>
<script>
    testClass.load();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, it seems to me /js/test.react.js cannot be dynamically loaded as pure JavaScript file. Can any expert explain to me the reason and provide a proper solution to write my wrapper API JavaScript file?

Comment: Cant you just compile into jsx every time? A grunt-task can do that automatically upon every code change.

Answer (score 3):

`JSXTransformer*.js` exports a global `JSXTransformer` object which has an `exec()` function, which transpiles JSX then `eval()`s the result.

You could try running `JSXTransformer.exec()` with the script's contents `onload` first.

Also, FYI, the [@jsx pragma is no longer required](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#the-jsx-pragma-is-gone) as of React 0.12 :)

Comment: JSXTransformer has been deprecated
https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html